# How to get Quarters for financial year based on date

Tags: excel, date, formula, finance

I'm trying to display quarters based on the financial year: Q1 starting in April, Q2 from July, etc.

In column `B` there is a list of dates, and in column `A` I want the corresponding quarter & year. There are 2 parts I can't figure out:

- currently for `01 JAN 2018` it shows `Q4 2018`. Although the date is 2018, it's the final quarter of 2017 and should show `Q4 2017`
- how to get the display format like `Q1 17/18` (eg)

At the moment I have:

```
=CHOOSE(INT((MONTH(B1)-1)/3)+1,"Q4","Q1","Q2","Q3") & " " & YEAR(B1)
```

Is it possible without any helper columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtract a Boolean expression from the Year part:

```
YEAR(B1) - (MONTH(B1)<4)
```

If the MONTH is Less than 4 it will subtract `1` from the year, otherwise it will subtract `0`:

```
=CHOOSE(INT((MONTH(B1)-1)/3)+1,"Q4","Q1","Q2","Q3") & " " & YEAR(B1) - (MONTH(B1)<4)
```

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you. I even managed to answer the second part of my own question, simply subtracted 2000 from the year and it shows 2018 as 18. Thanks!

Comment: @jay123 please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.